# Graphs and Quadratic Equations?

Tags: quadratics

**Question:**

A ball is dropped from a height of $18$ metres. The quadratic equation $h = -2t^2 + 18$ gives you the height, $h$ metres, of the ball, after $t$ seconds.

After how many seconds does the ball hit the ground?

**What I've tried so far:** I have tried rearranging the equation but that just got me to a dead end. I was thinking of tried to complete the square or factorising but I am not entirely sure. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: we're given a polynomial of degree 2, with a negative constant infront of the t^2 term. What would a graph of this function look like?

Comment: If it's negetive, will the graph be flipped upside down in terms of $-x^2$? I'm not sure...

Comment: Good! Now we're given h=8, so plug that in, and combine like terms. Plug it into a graphing application/calculator. What is the importance of the roots/zeroes?

Comment: Oopsy... Typo. I meant $h=18$. @RonaldB

Comment: @Hanka did you figure out what the importance of the zeroes is? Doesn't really matter what $h$ is.

Comment: Should I try to plug 0 into the equation and rearrange with like terms from there? @RonaldB

Comment: Is $t = 3$ by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the ball hits the ground means that $h=0$, how does this simplify our equation?